# how to concat a space with a symbol using c macro

Tags: c

```
#define var(N) variable ## N
```

var(1) got variable1

I want to get variable, how can I define the macro?

var( ) works, but it always give a warning. is there any other solutions?

Comment: why you need this weird macro... it's very confusing.

Comment: Please add the warning, and the line thats producing the warning

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it is an example, currently I am trying to rewrite some old code

Comment: @camino Do you want both `var(1)` and `var()` to work? Where the latter should expand to just `variable?`, making the macro argument optional?

Comment: GCC does not give any warning for me.

Comment: @unwind if var(1) can return "variable" is also fine. for example , I want var(1) ==>variable, var(2) ==>variable2, var(3) ==>variable3,

Comment: clang doesn't warn either with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. What are you using?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I got the warning in VC

Comment: Reopening the question, since other than the answer in the linked question claims, C and C++ **are** different in the preprocessor. Also the version of C or C++ plays a role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the version that you presented always needs a non-empty argument for `N`. If you have a modern C compiler you can use this construct:

```
#define var(...) variable ## __VA_ARGS__
```

This accepts empty arguments and you should be fine.

"modern" here means C as of 1999.

Comment: Notes on this answer: you must be using a C99 compiler (-std=c99 in gcc) or at least one that supports variadic macros. ## is the concatenation operator in the C preprocessor.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use the argument inside the macro:

```
#define var(n) variable
```

Comment: I guess the op would like to preserve the concatenation functionality

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh. Thanks, I didn't understand it correctly, then.